# Shipping charges are not saving in Database if we added Product to cart through Android App

Tags: soap-api-v2, android

we are using 2 shipping methods in our site.

1. Table rate shipping method
2. Custom shipping method  [ extension]

we are doing **Android** app for our magento site.

when we use default shipping methods [ example :  "**Table rate shipping method** " ,code : "tablerate_bestway" ] shipping charges are working fine in site and in andriod app.

when we use custom shipping method [ example : "**custom shipping method 1**" , code "ship_ship" ] shipping charges are working fine in site  **but we are getting "0" as shipping charges in android app** Because in APP, **shipping charges are not saving in "sales_flat_quote_shipping_rate " table** It showing "0" in that table.

this is the problem. what we need to do so that shipping charges should work in andriod app when we use custom shipping method.

Comment: What does https://www.magentocommerce.com/api/soap/checkout/cartShipping/cart_shipping.method.html return for you in the android app?

Comment: i wil check with andriod team now......

Comment: we are getting shipping charges as "0". we are not getting any error if we place the order through app.

Comment: Try debugging .... first figure out your quote ids for both web and android...   then add the same item to cart for both web and android take a look at  sales_flat_quote_address and sales_flat_quote_shipping_rate tables (fields - shipping method, weight, etc) to figure out a pattern of what the issue maybe. Without knowing the order in which the api are been called or what version of the api you are using it very debug remotely

Comment: @R.S Thanks for your valuable hints, we will check it.

Comment: Code snippets on how you are interacting with Magento, I'm assuming through the API? Would help expedite an answer.

Comment: @B00MER ye we are passing magento soap API username and API key to Android . so using java code Android team is interacting. IS that what you asked, otherwise please explain what code you want to see.

Comment: @B00MER if we add cart through APP, its not saving in "sales_flat_quote_shipping_rate" table

Comment: @R.S if we add cart through APP, its not saving in "sales_flat_quote_shipping_rate" table

Comment: Did you also enter the shipping info?

Comment: yes, we enter shipping info - name ,addess, zip code...etc...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First,You need to

check ***available shipping methods for current cart/Quote*** using  Soap api function `shoppingCartShippingList()`.See at [link](https://www.magentocommerce.com/api/soap/checkout/cartShipping/cart_shipping.list.html) .If you have ***`multiple store view/stores /websites`*** then you need to **send store id/code** as it parmas.

**Just like:** *$result = $proxy->shoppingCartShippingList($sessionId, 10,'default');*

**In  order to get shipping methods list for a cart**

- *`you  Should save customer shipping address for calculated before
  getting shipping  methods`*
- if **shoppingCartShippingList()** not give the shipping method then
  you need check backend setting means per as scope wish(at store /view
  /wise)

Comment: we are getting the shipping method using "shoppingCartShippingList()" . I want to know in which file, i need to place this code : $result = $proxy->shoppingCartShippingList($sessionId, 10,'default');

Comment: we are getting shipping methods , but main problem is its taking  " 0" as shipping charges...

Comment: dude,ask u developer  first to check  available shipping methods using below api https://www.magentocommerce.com/api/soap/checkout/cartShipping/cart_shipping.list.html

Comment: we are getting custom shipping methods also.

Comment: i checked with android devoloper, we are getting custom shipping method. but shipping charges are gettting zero only.