# where i need to place the code related to shipping method

Tags: api, soap, soap-api-v2, app

This question is different from following links question.

This is the problem : [Shipping charges are not saving in Database if we added Product to cart through Android App](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/95560/shipping-charges-are-not-saving-in-database-if-we-added-product-to-cart-through)

in the link's answer :

```
 $result = $proxy->shoppingCartShippingList($sessionId, 10,'default');
```

But i have no idea where i need to place this code. please guide me for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**List Of Enable Shipping Methods**

```
$result = $proxy->shoppingCartShippingList($sessionId, 10);   
var_dump($result);
```

**Set shipping method to order**

```
$result = $proxy->shoppingCartShippingMethod($sessionId, 10, 'freeshipping_freeshipping');
var_dump($result);
```

Comment: can you please tell where i have to , in which file i have to place this  above code.

Comment: are you working magento end or 3 party end?

Comment: we are using custom  extension.

Comment: are you need in custom extention?

Comment: we are using custom extension for shipping method. its working fine in site. we are getting shipping charges, but not in app.

Comment: yes, we need shipping charges for custom extension in app

Comment: if your trying $result = $proxy->shoppingCartShippingList($sessionId, 10);   
var_dump($result); 
then got custom shipping method?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/34184/discussion-between-abdul-and-baby-in-magento).

Comment: yes, we are getting shipping method, but not shipping charges we gave in backend. but its working in site, not in app